# pytest fixture yield returns generator instead of object

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, falconframework

I'm running pytest-3. I'm defining a fixture that is supposed to return a falcon TestClient object. I also need a teardown, so I'm trying to yield it.

```
def client():
    api=create_app()
    c = testing.TestClient(api)
    yield c
    remove_db()
```

If I 'return' instead of 'yield', the test cases run just fine.
But with yield, my test cases get a generator object instead of a TestClient object

Answer (score 4):

Probably because the function is not marked as a fixture. Try after decorating the function with `@pytest.fixture`. For example,

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def client():
    api=create_app()
    c = testing.TestClient(api)
    yield c
    remove_db()
```